# Loop through Array/Json Objects in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an array which consists of different nodes. following is the array when i print it using print_r($cruise).

```
Array ( [SearchCruise_ApiInfoResponse] => Array ( [SearchCruise_ApiInfoResult] => {"TirunServer": [{"Sail_Date":"11/10/2020","Nights":"22","Brand_Code":"Z","ShipName":"AZAMARA JOURNEY","DepartText":"LISBON, PORTUGAL","Package_Id":"JR22U001","Package_Description":" 22-NIGHT WESTERN AFRICA JOURNEY","Ship_code":"JR","I":null,"o":"8530","b":"9780","d":null,"Mincost_iobd":"8530","Taxes_and_Fees_Amount":"326.60","Guest_1_2_Gratuity_Amount":"110.25","Ports":"Lisbon, portugal - Portimao, portugal - Casablanca, morocco - Agadir, morocco - Lanzarote, canary islands - Gran canaria, canary islands - At sea - At sea - Banjul, the gambia - At sea - At sea - Abidjan, ivory coast - Takoradi, ghana - At sea - At sea - At sea - Luanda, angola - At sea - At sea - Walvis bay, namibia - Luderitz, namibia - At sea - Cape town, south africa","SailingDates":",11/10/2020","Guest_1_Non_Commissionable_Cruise_Fare_Amount":"669.00","Fare_Code_Description":"STANDARD","Total":1}], "TotalCount": {"RecordCount":1}} ) )
```

What i want to do is access the Node "TirunServer" and loop through it to print all the values in a tabular format.

Following is what i am doing.

```
foreach ($cruise as $key => $val){

foreach ($val as $key2 => $val2){

print_r($val2);

    for($i=0;$i<count($val2['TirunServer']);$i++){

        echo "okay = ".$val2['TirunServer'][$i]['Sail_Date'];
    }

}
}
```

i get the following while echoing ==> okay = {

Following is the value for print_r($val2)

```
{"TirunServer": [{"Sail_Date":"11/10/2020","Nights":"22","Brand_Code":"Z","ShipName":"AZAMARA JOURNEY","DepartText":"LISBON, PORTUGAL","Package_Id":"JR22U001","Package_Description":" 22-NIGHT WESTERN AFRICA JOURNEY","Ship_code":"JR","I":null,"o":"8530","b":"9780","d":null,"Mincost_iobd":"8530","Taxes_and_Fees_Amount":"326.60","Guest_1_2_Gratuity_Amount":"110.25","Ports":"Lisbon, portugal - Portimao, portugal - Casablanca, morocco - Agadir, morocco - Lanzarote, canary islands - Gran canaria, canary islands - At sea - At sea - Banjul, the gambia - At sea - At sea - Abidjan, ivory coast - Takoradi, ghana - At sea - At sea - At sea - Luanda, angola - At sea - At sea - Walvis bay, namibia - Luderitz, namibia - At sea - Cape town, south africa","SailingDates":",11/10/2020","Guest_1_Non_Commissionable_Cruise_Fare_Amount":"669.00","Fare_Code_Description":"STANDARD","Total":1}], "TotalCount": {"RecordCount":1}}
```

Any help

Comment: I think that `for($i=0;$i<count($val2['TirunServer']);$i++)` should be `foreach($val2->TirunServer as $key3 => $val3)` since TirunServer is a field in an object. The echo line would then be `echo "okay = ".$val3->Sail_Date;`

Comment: @Snake14 yep tried that. Got $val3 as blank

Comment: are you sure you posted the correct structure that you are trying to iterate over? What does `var_dump($cruise);` or `echo json_encode($cruise);` look like?

Comment: The Array which i've posted is print_r($cruise);

Comment: so what does $val2 look like when you print it out the same way?

Comment: @Snake14 please check the post. Added the value of print_r($val2)

Answer (score 0):

The $val2['TirunServer'] is array of objects, not array then you can not access like array.

Try this:

```
echo "okay = ".$val2['TirunServer'][$i]->Sail_Date;
```

Comment: Isn't "TirunServer" a field in an object as well? Shouldn't it be `$val2->TirunServer`...?

Comment: Tried to print the value $val2->TirunServer. Got blank

Comment: Can you print_r($cruise) then post the result?

Comment: @CongNguyen please check the post again. made relevant changes to the post itself

Comment: As result of print_r function, the $val2 is json string only, then you need to decode it before loop into child value.

$val2 = json_decode($val2);

then: $val2->TirunServer[0]->Sail_Date;

or $val2 = json_decode($val2, true); //decode to array

then: $val2->TirunServer[0]['Sail_Date'];